# multiple unions ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I've been looking for an example online for multiple unions on a single table, only solution  I found similar to the issue I am having is this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629659/merging-3-tables-queries-using-ms-access-union-query).

This is the query i've built in MS ACCESS

```
  SELECT chat_tb.tag_1 AS [tag_desc], Count(chat_tb.tag_1) AS [Count_of_tag] FROM chat_tb GROUP BY chat_tb.tag_1
UNION
SELECT chat_tb.tag_2 AS [tag_desc], Count(chat_tb.tag_2) AS [Count_of_tag]  FROM chat_tb GROUP BY chat_tb.tag_2
UNION 
SELECT chat_tb.tag_3 AS [tag_desc], Count(chat_tb.tag_3) AS [Count_of_tag]  FROM chat_tb GROUP BY chat_tb.tag_3;
```

But I get the following error, Im assuming since it is linking to MySQL table I cannot perform the union as the current syntax, can anyone assist me in changing it to mysql format, thank you in advance!

NOTE: If I remove the last union the statement works.

[View Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz0dv.png)

ODBC--call failed. 
{MySQL]{ODBC 3.51 Driver]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' Union (Select 'tag',Count('tag_2') FROM 'chat_tb" GROUP BY 'tag_2')) UNIO' at line 1 (#1064)

I found a another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804495/multiple-union-query-doesnt-work) similar issues.

and did the following:

```
 SELECT chat_tb.tag_1 AS [tag_desc], Count(chat_tb.tag_1) AS [Count_of_tag] FROM chat_tb GROUP BY chat_tb.tag_1;
UNION ALL (

SELECT chat_tb.tag_2 AS [tag_desc], Count(chat_tb.tag_2) AS [Count_of_tag]  FROM chat_tb GROUP BY chat_tb.tag_2;

UNION ALL

SELECT chat_tb.tag_3 AS [tag_desc], Count(chat_tb.tag_3) AS [Count_of_tag]  FROM chat_tb GROUP BY chat_tb.tag_3
));
```

This gives me a "Syntax error in union query"

Comment: Remove the first two semi-colons (ie the ones before the two union statements)

Comment: Also no need give each query the alias field name as the query will just use those on the first query - so can remove `AS [tag_desc]`, etc from second two queries.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock this did not change anything unfortunately, I think I require MySql SQL Statement since MS Access is Link to a MySQl table.

Comment: You may want to redesign your database to - you have fields `tag_1`, `tag_2` and `tag_3` which look like they hold the same kind of info.  Is `tag_2` and `tag_3` null if `tag_1` holds a value?  If so you could just have `tag` which holds text to differentiate between the three tags.  You could then just count tags and group by them to get the result you're after.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the new query that doesn't work and post the error, if it is now different?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Updates are made, same error Message.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook i do not have the option to modify this table unfortunately. tags 1 to 3 can contain null and both unique and duplicate values.

Comment: What does the error message say - can't the attached pic where I am at the moment? I take it `chat_tb` is a MySQL table and not an Access query that references a MySQL talbe?  Does it work if you remove one of the unions (as was possible in the linked thread)?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook yes When I take our the last union everything works fine.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook just inserted the error written in the original post

Comment: Pretty sure that last update will be the semi-colons.  You don't actually need to put any in, but if you do put one it it must be the very last character in the SQL statement.

Comment: Sorry just seen the other problem - you do not need the brackets

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I've tried the following removed all semi colons, inserted all semicolons, kept the last one and all produce the same exact error

Comment: It is a linked table and not a pass-through query isn't it?  I'm a bit confused as the error message says `tag` and `tag2` and `tag_2`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook its a linked table and not a pass through, sorry typo just adjusted the error both are written as tag_2

Comment: are you sure there's a space between union and select of the next line?

Comment: @xQbert no changes to the error

Comment: Sorry, not sure I can help further.  If all the suggestions so far haven't helped it's looking more like the MySQL side of things.  Saying that - just noticed your second SQL code block has an extra close bracket on the end.  As far as I can tell this should work:  `SELECT tag_1 AS [tag_desc], Count(tag_1) AS [Count_of_tag] FROM chat_tb GROUP BY tag_1 UNION SELECT tag_2, Count(tag_2) FROM chat_tb GROUP BY tag_2 UNION SELECT tag_3, Count(tag_3) FROM chat_tb GROUP BY tag_3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just managed to replicate your problem.  What you are doing is attempting to run the Query as an Access query on a MySQL linked table.  Having done a bit of research this appears to be a known bug: see [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=7684).  You cannot have more than one union.  It does however work as SQL Pass-Through. On the design tab select Pass-Through (globe symbol) under Union.  This does mean you need to select your DNS to run it.

Comment: This is an interesting bug. Still in MS Access 13/16 as bug points to much earlier version of Access and MySQL? How about if you remove parentheses around `SELECT` statements?

Comment: @Parfait I tried and tried.  I even tried cheating by splitting it into two Access queries (which both separately worked) and then doing the union on those; but no joy!  I think actually the bug is not in Access, but is in the ODBC driver, which comes from Oracle.  I have used ODBC in Access with other back-ends and never seen the same.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Thank you for this!

Comment: @NoobPrgmr My pleasure.  Have a great day.